# JDBC Closing Resources

Tags: java, jdbc, connection, resultset

I am unsure whether a statement and resultset should be closed after each query or after all my queries have been made (ie at the same time i close the connection)?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure both work?

However, would the database eventually crash if I didn't close a statement after each query and then performed a lot of queries?

On the other hand, would it be inefficient and time-wasting to keep closing & creating statements for every query?

I've read up a lot on this problem before asking this question, but I'm still uncertain.  Any help appreciated,

tre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2ee/JDBC.htm#JDBC118:

> **Close ResultSet when finished**
>
> Close ResultSet object as soon as you finish working with ResultSet
>   object even though Statement object closes the ResultSet object
>   implicitly when it closes, closing ResultSet explicitly gives chance
>   to garbage collector to recollect memory as early as possible because
>   ResultSet object may occupy lot of memory depending on query.

In a nutshell, you don't *have* to explicitly close your `ResultSet` objects, but it's better to do so to free up memory earlier on.  Failing to close your `ResultSet` objects will just cause the memory that it occupies (which can be small, or large, depending on the size of the result set) to be occupied until the corresponding `Statement` object is closed.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for the answer.  I'd read this previously but was unsure about it - does this mean that I should close the ResultSet after each query, but only close the statement after carrying out all queries?  Thanks.

Comment: @tre I elaborated on my answer.  Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: It did, and sorry for asking for further clarification but it would really help - does this mean that every resultset for a single statement would be kept until the statement closed?  Thanks, very much, thumbs up. Edit: I have to wait a minute to says it's the right answer:)

Comment: If you get multiple ResultSets from a Statement, then they will all stay open until you either 1) close the ResultSet objects manually or 2) close the Statement. If you are getting multiple ResultSets from a single Statement, then it is a better idea to close the unused ResultSets when you're done with them, or your application will continue to occupy more space in memory. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

How much this matters really depends on the specifics of what you're doing. But generally it's better to close a resultset (in a finally block). From everything I've always read and seen, opening the connection itself is where the performance penalties are.

What you *don't* want to do is open/close connections very quickly (this is why many applications and servers implement connection pooling).

Comment: Thanks very much this really, really helped - opening/closing connections very quickly is exactly what I was about to be doing with my current code, so now I know that I definitely shouldn't.  However, what about opening/closing a statement after each query - would this also be bad and unnecessary?

Comment: I doubt it'd hurt much to close and re-create the Statement, but I wouldn't close the statement if I were doing a few queries in one go.